# How to show custom property as enum?

Tags: python, objects, customization, properties

So I have created a custom channel box for animating.  And it has all the transforms in it, and can dynamicly update the custom properties per object I select.  However the custom properties only show as Int, or Float, or String in the channel box.  But in the "Custom Properties" panel  I have an Enum, and it shows like normal.
[image]

I want to know how to get that enum to show correctly in my channel box.

here is my snip-it of code:

```
myList = []
    for k in obj.keys():
        myList.append(k)

    prefix = ( 'cycles', '_RNA_UI' )
    newList = [ x for x in myList if not x.startswith( prefix ) ]

    addTo = '[' + '"'
    addAftr = '"' + ']'

    newName = [ x + addAftr for x in newList ]
    newName2 = [ addTo + y for y in newName ]



    for n in newName2:
        splitr = n.split( '[' )[1]
        splitr2 = splitr.split( '"' )[1]

        custmAttr = layout.row()
        custmAttr.prop(obj, n, text = splitr2)
```

Any help is appreciated.